# How do I auto-refresh eww pages?

Tags: eww

If I load a local file, I'd like eww to refresh when the source is changed. This would be similar to auto-revert mode. Is there any way to do this? Right now I have to manually refresh by hitting `g` in the `*eww*` buffer.

Comment: If you're comfortable with elisp, then [How can I make ibuffer auto-refresh the list of buffers?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2179/454) has some useful details on implementing custom support for `auto-revert-mode`, which may point you in the right direction.

Comment: You should probably fill a bug report requesting `eww` to respect `auto-revert-mode` for local files (also `file-buffer-name` for that matter).  If you don't want to that you can try to combine `(info "(elisp) File Notifications")` and `eww-current-url`.  You might have to map through all `*eww*` buffers when something changes to find the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

- Start a `file-notify` watch when opening a file in `eww`.
- In the callback function for that watch, do 2 things:

  - Reload the *eww* buffer every time the function is triggered by `file-notify` event.
  - Log the event descriptors specific to file opening actions in `eww`. This is because you need to know which `file-notify` watches to remove when you quit `eww` (especially if you use the watches for other purposes than this too).
- On quitting `eww` remove all the watches related to `eww`. You have to make sure that you call this specific function to quit `eww` and clean up the now-not-required watches.

## How to use

- Copy the below implementation to your `init.el`.
- Launch any file you want to load in `eww` using `C-u M-x eww-open-file`.
- Make sure you quit `eww` by calling `modi/eww-quit-and-update-fn-descriptors`. For convenience, the default binding <kbd>q</kbd> in `eww-mode-map` is now bound to this function. If you use any other binding to quit `eww` or to kill windows, make sure you call this function. `modi/eww-quit-and-update-fn-descriptors` ensures that the eww-specific file-notify watches are removed.

## Implementation

```el
(defvar modi/eww--file-notify-descriptors-list ()
  "List to store file-notify descriptor for all files that have an
associated auto-reloading eww buffer.")

(defun modi/advice-eww-open-file-to-auto-reload (orig-fun &rest args)
  "When `eww-open-file' is called with \\[universal-argument], open
the file in eww and also add `file-notify' watch for it so that the eww
buffer auto-reloads when the HTML file changes."
  (prog1
      (apply orig-fun args)
    (when current-prefix-arg ; C-u M-x eww-open-file
      (require 'filenotify)
      (let ((file-name (car args)))
        (file-notify-add-watch file-name
                               '(change attribute-change)
                               #'modi/file-notify-callback-eww-reload)
        ;; Show the HTML file and its rendered form in eww side-by-side
        (find-file-other-window file-name))
      ;; Redefine the `q' binding in `eww-mode-map'
      (bind-key "q" #'modi/eww-quit-and-update-fn-descriptors eww-mode-map))))
(advice-add 'eww-open-file :around #'modi/advice-eww-open-file-to-auto-reload)

(defun modi/file-notify-callback-eww-reload (event)
  "On getting triggered, switch to the eww buffer, reload and switch
back to the working buffer. Also save the `file-notify-descriptor' of the
triggering event."
  (let* ((working-buffer (buffer-name)))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window "eww")
    (eww-reload)
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window working-buffer))
  ;; `(car event)' will return the event descriptor
  (add-to-list 'modi/eww--file-notify-descriptors-list (car event)))

(defun modi/eww-quit-and-update-fn-descriptors ()
  "When quitting `eww', first remove any saved file-notify descriptors
specific to eww, while also updating `modi/eww--file-notify-descriptors-list'."
  (interactive)
  (dotimes (index (safe-length modi/eww--file-notify-descriptors-list))
    (file-notify-rm-watch (pop modi/eww--file-notify-descriptors-list)))
  (quit-window :kill))
```

## Assumptions

- You have only one *eww* buffer open.
- This solution requires emacs 24.4 or newer.

Comment: Awesome. Unfortunately file notification doesn't work yet on OS X. I'll give this a shot on my other machine which runs Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue with a noob solution so here it is:

I basically added a hook that calls `eww-reload` on the "other frame" -that supposedly has the web page open- once the markdown gets saved.

This works fine for me as I usually have my window split into two frames only when I'm writing in markdown, one for md and the other for preview -using either doc-view or eww-

So here is the snippet I added to my init.el, please read carefully and edit according to your situation:

```
(defun compile-md ()
  "Run available makefile that should compile markdown to whatever."
  (interactive)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'markdown-mode)
    (shell-command "make")); that make file uses pandoc to compile md to html
  (windmove-right); supposing the eww frame is on the right 
  (when (derived-mode-p 'eww-mode)
    (eww-reload))
  (windmove-left); get back to the md buffer
 )

(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'compile-md)
```

Comment: You can probably advantageously replace the `windmove-left` with `save-window-excursion` (or even better `save-current-buffer` if you can replace the `windmove-right` with a function which changes the current buffer rather than the selected window).